# How to avoid asking previously asked questions, yet gain reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, new-users

I have recently joined Stack Overflow. Mostly, I am searching well on my programming questions here and can find answers on my own, yet this approach does not help with my Stack Overflow reputation, as it seems that almost all the basic/intermediate level questions I can come up with have been previously asked. I also see many questions flagged as previously asked, answered, etc. What would be your advice to build up reputation on Stack Overflow for a newcomer to this site? It seems right now I can only ask questions, not even answer. :-)

Edit: People who flagged my question as duplicate haven't even read it. It is about how to gain reputation while all questions are marked as duplicates. Probably there are bots marking all genuine questions as duplicates. The link provided does not help with my question.

Edit 2: I noticed that the ones who mark my question as duplicate have very high reputation and are ranked top 10% among all contributors on StackOverFlow. Would be nice if they actually took time to answer the question.

Comment: The deleted answers to this question are utterly depressing: 'if you want easy rep, help fill the site with trash by answering new questions quickly.  They are likely low-quality dupes, but just ignore that, they will get upvoted anyway' :(

Comment: @MartinJames Your comment has convinced me, that the site *requires* this post, so I undeleted it.

Comment: This question seems to say that you are able to get help with the programming issues you have, but you are having difficulty getting reputation for the site.  From my point of view, really only the first part matters.  Granted I've got a bit of rep now, but I view it more about helping people.  Not having the biggest number.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Edit posts. Each accepted edit gives you +2 rep.

- Correct grammar.
- Fix spelling.
- Improve capitalization and punctuation.
- Format code.
- Remove chatter (e.g. "cheers", "good morning", "thanks in advance", "I'm a newb but...."), etc.

Comment: well I want to improve my coding and have a reputation for coding expert, not for grammar and spelling :)

Answer (score -3):

Write answers. To gain many rep, the only way is to write many answers to questions.

With edits, the +2 is actually not too much, and you can't do too much edit, too (you may have at most 5 pending edits). Getting an useful reputation with edits is a tremendous, repetitive work, much higher as it seems.

You also can't get rep with questions:

- First, the ratio of the negative votes (down, close, del) are much higher for the questions. It seems, they are not so popular.
- You get only +5 with a question upvote, but lose -2 with a down. And they are also free for the downvoters, while answer downs cost also them -1.
- Writing a question is a heck a big work. You need to react the comments, edit the question according them, *defend it* (there are often initiatives for closure or critical comments, you need to react them quickly with convincing arguments and edits), understand the answers what you get and react them accordingly. It is much higher work than writing an answer, maybe reacting some comments and smiling on the ups.

You can get the most upvotes to the answers of new questions.

Don't worry if you don't get upvotes on the spot. Around half of the upvotes arrive within a day, the rest later. Around from some thousands of answers you will get the upvotes continuously and you will practically always see the green rectangle.

When you can first know, how successful is your post, is its score next morning.

Comment: Thank you peter for the insight.